# Make an int equal a value between two numbers?

Tags: javascript

Say that I have an int = 30;.  Instead of just having an int equal a number (like 30) how would I make the int = any value between say 30 and 80?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you share a little more on what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps a code snippet?

Comment: so you have a lower bound and an upper bound

Comment: Do you want a pseudo-random number in that range?

Comment: @cgatian it is pretty clear what he is trying to accomplish

Comment: @RPM: Then maybe you can share what you know? I don't see it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **JavaScipt**:

```
var x = Math.floor( Math.random()*(81-30) +30);
```

See Math object description on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

Comments on this answer have suggested that the value `Math.floor` return is "arbitrary". However, it is a `Number`. See [ECMAScript 3 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), "15.8.2.9 floor(x)", page 162. And according to the same specification ("8.5 The Number Type", page 29), a Number value is a `double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754` value. Or to put it in words the average programmer understand: A "double" or a "float" type. If you have the book [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000480) close at hand, then you can read about the Number type from page 31 ("3.1 Numbers") and forwards.

My old answer thought you said Java:

<strike>Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(81 - 30) + 30;</strike>

See [Random API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Comment: oh sorry. Updated the answer. It's right now ain't it? I've had a sip of the whisky bottle tonight so maybe I shouldn't be hanging around on SO.

Comment: Parsing an int can be done in a couple of ways in JS. Most straight forward would be to wrap the call in `window.parseInt`.

Comment: Hey I stand corrected about that window.parseInt thing. I shall make an edit and elaborate a bit on that in my answer. Reload page in a few minutes!

Comment: Anonymous user, I wrote a quick test case and saw that I got the numbers wrong. I updated my post! Use `81-30` and **not** `80-30` okay? This will ensure that your random result, x, is always between 30 and 80 inclusive.

Comment: ..and be sure to tick my post as an answer if you think it is =)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="result"></div>

var min = 30;
var max = 80;

document.getElementById("result").textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/brFpc/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getInt(lo, hi) {
    var l = parseInt(lo);
    var h = parseInt(hi);
    return parseInt(Math.random() * (h - l)) + l;
}

function isBetween(x, lb, ub) {
    return x >= lb && x <= ub;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var lo = 30, hi = 80
    var x = getInt(lo, hi);
    var b = isBetween(x, lo, hi);
    document.write(x + '-' + b + '<br/>');
}
```

[Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/P63KX/)